# How to manipulate the menuitem using arcobjects?

Tags: vb.net-2010, arcgis, arcmap, arcobjects

In arcobjects, there is an option to create customized BaseMenu. Similarly is there any option to modify the existing [customized]BaseMenu? Kindly clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I usually create custom menus in ArcMap using the [IMenuDef Interface](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IMenuDef_Interface/00430000003r000000/).  Most of my menus are on custom toolbars similar to [this example](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000002wp000000).